# How does doing PhD studies with an interpreter work?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, language

From [this article](https://vnexplorer.net/?#chinese-god-wei-mathematical-genius-showcases-talent-by-solving-problem-in-one-night-that-stumped-team-of-phds-for-months-s1321526.html):

> According to Jiupai News, Wei also turned down an offer from Harvard to study as a PhD candidate, even though the school promised to waive his English competency test and provide him with an interpreter.

I can't imagine doing PhD studies with an interpreter. One can't possibly rely on an interpreter for lectures, for example. How does it work?

Comment: I would think it would not work well long term, but could bridge the time until the person's English improves.